# How to change scope of 'this' in settings for custom jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scope

With a lot of jQuery functions I am able to write a bit of code like this:

```
$('.element').css({
    'width':    $(this).width() * 2
});
```

By using $(this) I can find the width of .element.

How can I make a plugin of my own invention work the same way?

```
$('.element').myPlugin({
    'setting':    $(this).width() * 2
});
```

Just for demonstrative purposes, this is potentially what my plugin code looks like:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(settings){

    // Settings
    var defaults = {
        'setting':    'value'
    };

    var o = $.extend(defaults, settings);

    // For every instance
    return this.each(function(){

        // Do something

    });

};
```

Hope that makes sense, and if anyone can suggest a better title for this question, feel free! It is hard to search for something when you don't know what terms to use!

Answer (score 0):

Can you prove that this:

```js
$('.element').css({
    'width':    $(this).width() * 2
});
```

works as you describe???  I would very confused if it did.

Comment: in the same context, you can use this to initialize your plugin?  You're seeing jQuery bind this to the target inside the click handler.

Comment: Ahh, ok, thank you for explaining. I really should have figured that out by now!